# Linux image extra for kernel 4.4.1

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to play around with docker, but still stuck on the installation process (based on [docker installation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/)), on this :

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`

It gimme error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.4.1-040401-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-4.4.1-040401-generic'
```

I'm using kernel 4.4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 btw.

So, how could I install this linux-image-extra packages, if I can't get it from the repo or from [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.1-wily/)?? Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: @Pilot6 any ideas, to solve it? compile from source maybe? But I never build kernel from source :3

Comment: Just do not install extra. They do not build extra for all kernels. In some cases all code is in the main image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image is built without `extra` package.

So you do not need to install that package. Just install these:

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.1-wily/linux-headers-4.4.1-040401-generic_4.4.1-040401.201601311534_amd64.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.1-wily/linux-headers-4.4.1-040401_4.4.1-040401.201601311534_all.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.1-wily/linux-image-4.4.1-040401-generic_4.4.1-040401.201601311534_amd64.deb
```

This is if your system is 64-bit.

The easiest way is to download debs to your home folder and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4.1*.deb linux-image-4.4.1*.deb
```

Comment: in other words, I've installed it, since I did install the kernel in that way. I'll try to skip the step and go to the next step.

Comment: well, yep. That's solve my problem hahaha.. Thanks btw. Arrgh, so much wasting time trying to configure this out :D

Comment: But I see no reason to install another kernel for docky.

Comment: I thought that they've made an error and added extra to depends.

Comment: I have no idea :D The most important thing is, I could use docker right now hahaha.. I even tried to compile kernel from source patched it with aufs (or something) and it ended fail. And, by the way, the docker's installation page might assume someone using default installation. Kernel 4.4.1 seems to much newer compared to repo version.